Issues with Django Rest Framework Serializer for Nested Data Handling
I’m working on a Django project using Django Rest Framework (DRF), and I’m facing issues with serializing and deserializing nested data for my Child model. Here’s a summary of my setup and the problem:
**I have the following Django models:
**
class Hobbies(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class BehaviorChallenges(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class StandardTestScore(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    learning_style = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gpa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    hobbies = models.ManyToManyField(Hobbies, related_name="children")
    behavior_challenges = models.ManyToManyField(BehaviorChallenges, related_name="children")
    standard_test_score = models.ManyToManyField(StandardTestScore, through='TestScoreThroughModel', related_name="children")
    adding_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class TestScoreThroughModel(models.Model):
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    standard_test_score = models.ForeignKey(StandardTestScore, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

**Here’s the ChildSerializer that I’ve set up:
**
class TestScoreThroughModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=StandardTestScore.objects.all())
    score = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = TestScoreThroughModel
        fields = ['id', 'score']

class ChildSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hobbies = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Hobbies.objects.all())
    behavior_challenges = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, queryset=BehaviorChallenges.objects.all())
    standard_test_score = TestScoreThroughModelSerializer(many=True, source='testscorethroughmodel_set')

    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = [
            'parent', 'name', 'age', 'gender', 'learning_style', 'gpa', 'grade', 
            'hobbies', 'behavior_challenges', 'standard_test_score'
        ]

    def create(self, validated_data):
        test_scores_data = validated_data.pop('testscorethroughmodel_set', [])
        child = Child.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for test_score_data in test_scores_data:
            TestScoreThroughModel.objects.create(child=child, **test_score_data)
        return child


**When I send the following JSON payload using Postman, I get validation errors:
**
{
    "parent": 1,
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": "10",
    "gender": "Male",
    "learning_style": "Visual",
    "gpa": "3.5",
    "grade": "5",
    "hobbies": [1, 2],
    "behavior_challenges": [1],
    "standard_test_score": [
        {"id": 1, "score": 85},
        {"id": 2, "score": 90}
    ]
}



Errors:
{
    "hobbies": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ],
    "behavior_challenges": [
        "Incorrect type. Expected pk value, received str."
    ],
    "standard_test_score": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}


Checking the Data Types: Ensured that hobbies and behavior_challenges are sent as arrays of integers.
Verifying standard_test_score: Ensured that standard_test_score is sent as an array of objects with id and score.

Your code should work, if settings and views are correct too. I've repeated your code, and everything works correctly. Can you give some information about views?

@api_view(['POST'])
def child_register(request):
serializer = ChildSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
serializer.save()
return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

Here also, code is correct. May be there issues in the drf module. Try to re-init venv, debug with/without justMyCode.

As you said, the problem wasn't from the code, I created a new env, and things worked fine. Thx for the help

The error *"This field is required."* standard_test_score field is not correctly mapped.

correct code:
class TestScoreThroughModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    standard_test_score = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=StandardTestScore.objects.all())
    score = serializers.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = TestScoreThroughModel
        fields = ['standard_test_score', 'score']
# Remaining errors indicated that 
The serializer is expecting primary key values (integers) for hobbies and behavior_challenges, but it’s receiving string values.
The array you are passing it's getting passed as a string from POSTMAN. Just print and check.


for standard_test_score, it still same error, however for the other two, hobbies and behavior_challenges, you were correct I have checked it was str, so I have changed it to list of pk, but, still not working, it expects only one integer
